# Divisor antichain related algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, project-euler

I have thought about [problem 386](https://projecteuler.net/problem=386) for 2 months and I have given up. A divisor antichain of a number is a subset of its (positive) divisors no one of which is divisible by another (e.g. for $30$ $(2,3,5)$ is an antichain). The problem is to find the sum of the length of all maximal length divisor antichains of numbers from $2$ to $10^8$ (for $30$ it is easy to see that it is $3$). [For individual numbers the maximal length can be calculated](https://oeis.org/A096825/internal) (given we know the number of distinct prime factors and their degree (e.g. $60$ is of the form $p^2qr$ where $p,q,r$ are $2,3,5$)) .

(Given that, I guess, the acceptable number of unit tasks in a ProjectEuler problems is about $10^7$ so even if we knew the factorisations of all numbers up to $10^8$ the algorithm would be too slow. Another problem is that I don't see how we can avoid knowing all primes up to $10^8$ (their list would take up too much memory space) and solve it.)

I tried to connect the problem to [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth's_theorem) but that didn't help.

Can you give me a hint? I won't submit the solution now and I don't want to copy-paste the answer to unlock forum discussions because so few people have solved it (every result of Google for this problem seems to be running too slowly).

The length of the divisor antichain for squarefree numbers is given by [Sperner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner's_theorem).

Comment: Given that $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots$  you can find the length of the longest antichain given only $e_1,e_2,\dots$, in fact the order of the exponents does not matter.  There are only a small number of partitions that can occur as the exponents of a number less than 10^8, for each of these partitions count the number of integers whose prime factorization has those exponents.

Comment: @deinst I thought of that but how do I do this without knowing the primes up to $10^8$? I won't be able to decide how many partitions a prime will contribute to (e.g. if a prime ($p$) is smaller than $\frac {10^8}{10}$ then it will be in $2p, 2^2p,2^3p,3p,3^2p,5p,2*3p,7p,2*5p$ but if it's bigger than $\frac {10^8}{7}$ it won't be in $7p,2^3p,2*5p$ from these )

Comment: You will need to find all of the primes up to 10^8, but you don't need to keep them.  For all of the numbers $n$ less than 10^4 figure out the largest antichain for $np$, then run once quickly through the primes greater than 10^4.  For the rest, you only need to store the primes less than 10^4.

Comment: @deinst Thanks, I assumed from the beginning that I didn't have time to compute the primes because it would be $O(10^8)$ and if I do it with a cross-out sieve method I would need a $10^8$ long list